# Which MySQL type best stores point in time information - Datetime or Timestamp

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, timestamp, iso8601

### Introduction

I realise similar questions have been asked here before. But I still needed to do a bit more testing for my use case - and am I little surprised/confused by the outcome.

The following is a description (with code) of the test and results.

I'm working on an application that:

- Records event history (things that happened at a point in time).

  - This history is immutable. Once an event is written, we do not change it.
  - We report on this history.
- Schedules future, possibly recurrent, actions. For example, "every Friday do this check."

So a clear understanding of time data is very important.

I am trying understand the timestamp types in MySQL (datetime and timestamp) and how they interact with Java code and ISO8601 timestrings.

I've read the MySQL docs around its Timestamp type - how it converts a time value to store it as UTC and, on retrieval, converts that UTC value to the server or session time zone.  That sounded like good "point-in-time" storage.

The datetime MySQL type is bit more opaque. This article (http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/timestamp-vs-datetime-which-should-i-be-using) considers it to be not so different from a string.
I repeated the "SELECT NOW() + 0;" query and got the same kind of answer as the article.

To try to clarify things, I wrote a small Java class that wrote to a single database table comprised of 3 columns:

- tz (String denoting the standard timezone id). UTC is used the tests - but it is not a timezone.
- mydatetime (Datetime column)
- mytimestamp (Timestamp column)

### Java code

The Java code is located here: https://gist.github.com/iliomad/c6d8a50613fa99e2d079b8ad3b9eca4d

### Test 1

I created 3 different ISO8601 timestamp strings - all for the same point in time - but with different offsets/timezones. 
Each was written the to database, retrieved and printed out.

To start with I set the MySQL database server time zone to "+00:00".

**Output**

Writing times to the database.

```
UTC
2018-04-13T11:12:00Z, 1523617920
Europe/Amsterdam
2018-04-13T13:12:00+02:00, 1523617920
Asia/Calcutta
2018-04-13T16:42:00+05:30, 1523617920
```

Reading stored times from database.

```
Description, Datetime column (epoch seconds), Datetime column (as ISO string), Timestamp column (as epoch seconds), Timestamp column (as ISO string)
UTC, 1523617920, 2018-04-13T11:12:00Z, 1523617920, 2018-04-13T11:12:00Z
Europe/Amsterdam, 1523617920, 2018-04-13T13:12+02:00[Europe/Amsterdam],       1523617920, 2018-04-13T13:12+02:00[Europe/Amsterdam]
Asia/Calcutta, 1523617920, 2018-04-13T16:42+05:30[Asia/Calcutta], 1523617920, 2018-04-13T16:42+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]
```

All looks good. The epoch seconds, when put into something like https://www.epochconverter.com/, agree with the ISO8601 time strings.

### Test 2

I then changed the timezone of the MySQL server from UTC (+00:00) to Europe/Amsterdam (+02:00) and read the stored times again.

**Output**

Reading stored times from database.

```
Description, Datetime column (epoch seconds), Datetime column (as ISO string), Timestamp column (as epoch seconds), Timestamp column (as ISO string)
UTC, 1523617920, 2018-04-13T11:12:00Z, 1523625120, 2018-04-13T13:12:00Z
Europe/Amsterdam, 1523617920, 2018-04-13T13:12+02:00[Europe/Amsterdam], 1523625120, 2018-04-13T15:12+02:00[Europe/Amsterdam]
Asia/Calcutta, 1523617920, 2018-04-13T16:42+05:30[Asia/Calcutta], 1523625120, 2018-04-13T18:42+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]
```

My expectation was the Datetime column would be affected - thinking it did not store timezone information. However, it was the Timestamp column that moved.

### Conclusion

We will not routinely be changing our server timezone. 
I'm trying to see which MySQL data type best represents a point in time - something I can count on as accurate and unchanging (and not head-wrecking). On the basis of the above, if I supply point-in-time info in the form of an ISO8601 string, the Datetime MySQL type retains the supplied information.

It's perfectly possible that my test code is incorrect and/or my interpretation of the results is.
Could do with a little guidance here.

In the test case above, is the Datetime MySQL type doing a better job of storing the point in time information?

Comment: The big gotcha is the JDBC driver, and the conversions it does/tries to do for timezone differences when the MySQL session `time_zone` does not match the JVM `-Duser.timezone`. With MySQL Connector/J, a variety of (seemingly bizarre) behaviors depends on settings of `useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift`, `useLegacyDatetimeCode` and `serverTimezone`  AND on the detection of MySQL datatypes and mapping to JDBC datatypes... strings and integers can pass through unscathed, but the JDBC datetime types can get munged.

Comment: Also be aware of the timezone conversions that happen with MySQL when the session time_zone does not match the server (global) time_zone.

Comment: @spencer7593 - Thanks, I'll be more careful with the DB timezone/JDBC timezone/JVM timezone alignment and see how things go. Frustrating how many layers in the stack need to have an opinion on timezones though.

Comment: Why don’t you just do `p.setObject(3, instant);` for writing the timestamp and `rs.getObject("mytimestamp", Instant.class)` for reading it? Assuming you are using at least JDBC 4.2 (which has been available for MySQL for years), you have no use for `java.sql.Timestamp`, and that class is long outdated. Also I suspect that my proposed changes may change your outcome to agree more with what you had expected.

Comment: @OleV.V.  Hmm. Tried that (and found your earlier info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075870/why-does-java-sql-timestamp-extend-java-util-date).  When I try the setObject as you describe, I get the error `Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x0Djava.time.Ser\x95]\x84\xBA\x1B"H\xB2\x0C\x00\x00xpw\x0D\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00Z\xD0\x90\x80\x00\x00\x00\x' for column 'mytimestamp' at row 1`. (Same error on the datetime column).  I'm using Java 8 with MySQL 5.7.18 and MySQL Connector/J v5.1.46.  According to MySQL docs this setup supports JDBC 4.2

Comment: Sorry to hear that, and sorry, I don’t have the experience to make a clearcut statement on the fix. What are the datatypes of your database columns? It was my understanding that you should prefer to use `Instant` with MySQL `timestamp` and Java `LocalDateTime` with MySQL `datetime`. Hope you can sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more tweaking, I got a Java class that manages to store and retrieve point-in-time information. I'm still a bit jittery on this - so many parts want to have a say in the time and that makes me uncomfortable.

The class is on the original gist here: https://gist.github.com/iliomad/c6d8a50613fa99e2d079b8ad3b9eca4d (and revisions show changes).

- I can change the MySQL server timezone to anything I wish. I still get out what I put in.

  - A query directly in the MySQL query manager also behaves - the timestamp column as unix epoch holds steady. That's what I expect.
  - select tz, mydatetime, unix_timestamp(mydatetime) as mydatetime_as_epoch, unix_timestamp(mytimestamp) from basic_time;
  - tz = timezone id (String);  mydatetime (Datetime column); mytimestamp (Timestamp column)
- Timestamp MySQL type is a timestamp. I don't need to mess with it.

  - Java 8 java.sql.Timestamp class fromInstant and toInstant methods claim to maintain the same point in time.
  - I tried Instant on the setObject and getObject preparedStatement methods. MySQL connector/J just does not accept them - I dug into the source code for a look.
- Datetime MySQL type I'm still a bit confused by (I don't know what it is) but knowing the timezone I can maintain the point-in-time information.
- I tried both the MySQL Connector/J 5.1.46 and 8.0.11 versions. Same behaviour for each.
- The JDBC parameter useLegacyDatetimeCode=false seems to be important. I need to run more tests with and without this to confirm.

Not quite up to analysing this completely just yet. Not fun trying to figure this out.